# Activity + Fragment + Service + Moxy

Tags: java, android, android-service, moxy

Вообщем есть приложение которое состоит из одного `Activity` и множества `Fragment`. В проекте используется MVP библиотека `Moxy`.

У меня есть `Fragment` чата (фрагмент переписки с другим юзером) и `Websocket` сервис который я привязываю к главной `Activity`.

`Activity` реализует интерфейс:

```
public interface WebsocketEventListener {

    void onMessage(String s);
}
```

который я потом передаю в `WebsocketService` после привязки, и  таким способом я смогу получать сообщение в активити из сервиса.

Вопрос в том, каким образом мне передавать данные из `Activity` во `Fragment`'ты, и как это сделать правильно используя MVP элементы из библиотеки `Moxy`.

Щас главная `Activity` выглядит примерно так:

```
public class MainActivity extends MvpAppCompatActivity implements MainView , WebscoketListener{

    //...


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to WebsocketService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebscoketService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }


    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mService.addListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String message){
        //receive message from WebsocketService
    }

     @Override
    public void showChatFragment() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, ChatFragment.getInstance(this.mainPresenter))
                .addToBackStack(ChatFragment.TAG)
                .commit();
    }
    //...
}
```